# Removing <br> tag from the page

Tags: javascript

here is function for the third layer of the tree map

```
            for (i=0;i<arr3.getNumberOfRows();i++){
            var rows3= [arr3.getValue(i,0)+'\n  Ticker: '+arr3.getValue(i,1)+'< br >'+'Instrument Desscription: '
            +arr3.getValue(i,4)+'<br>'+'Number Of Trades: '+arr3.getValue(i,6)+'< br > P&L: $'+arr3.getValue(i,7),
            arr3.getValue(i,3)+' '+arr3.getValue(i,8),arr3.getValue(i,6)-1+1,arr3.getValue(i,7)-1+1]

            layer2rows.push(rows3);

            }
            return layer2rows;
            }
```

This is a part of the code for Google tree map. I have three layers to it. I want to display the breaks in the line that is I don't want the information to display on one single line when I hover over the node. This code actually solves that problem that is when i hover over the there is break in theline in the tooltip where I want but now these break tags appear on the node head.

Comment: Could you demonstrate this in action, with a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar, to let us see what's going on? I don't think I understand your description of the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you are asking here, and whatever your code is doing is not very clear. Please explain more clearly, and provide more code (specifically when you are firing these events and the relevant parts of your html).

Answer (score 0):

try with...

```
rows3.replace('<br>','');
```

or with jQuery:

```
$('br').each(function(){

    $(this).remove();

});
```